# Непонятная ошибка с embed

Tags: discord.py

Решил создать викторину в дискорд боте. Человек вводит команду на сервере и бот отправляет вопросы ему в личные сообщения. Код выдает ошибку SyntaxError: invalid syntax, ссылаясь на строку embed.add_field.
Что нужно исправить?

```
@client.command()
async def викторина(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.author.send(
        embed=discord.Embed(title='** ВИКТОРИНА "название" **', color=0x0080ff)
        embed.add_field(name='Автор **имя**')
        embed.set_footer(text='При нахождении багов, пишите **ссылка**')

        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@client.command()
async def викторина(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    embed=discord.Embed(title='** ВИКТОРИНА "название" **', color=0x0080ff)
    embed.add_field(name=" Автор **имя** ", value='что-то', inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text=' текст ')
    await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
```